# mysql will slow after a couple of hours and need restarted to work

Tags: windows, mysql, performance

i have a windows 7 server just have mysql installed.

i will connect to it on a local network after a while of working server response slowly and cant answer requests correctly..

my clients have up to 3k-4k request per seconds

the server have two xeon cpu with 64 gig ram and some 10 k sas hard disk

but cpu usage is lower then 10% and ram usage is about 2 gigs

my mysql configuration is like this:

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_connection=5000
max_allowed_packet = 10M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer_size = 20M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 80M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 16
query_cache_size = 32M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 8

log-bin=mysql-bin

server-id   = 1

innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

how can i get a better performance this ?

Comment: Can you give stats when server perform slow? need I/O, CPU, memory, network and slow query details with number of active connection at that time.

Comment: windows work fine when mysql is slow and dont responding.how can i monitor i/o status?

Comment: check this https://serverfault.com/questions/188589/windows-record-i-o-stats-eqivalent-to-iostat

Comment: How many 10k spindles, in what type of array? Might get 100 IOPS each, not counting parity or mirrored writes.

Comment: @peimanF.  Because this is essentially a duplicate of dba.stackexchange.com Question 240147 would it be reasonable to ask the moderator to REMOVE this question from serverfault.com?

Answer (score 0):

What Engine are you using for your tables?  It *should* be InnoDB.  In this case, you should configure

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20G
```

(Or perhaps more; how much data do you have?)

Use the slowlog to find the slow queries, then let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.